# Delete action on a user management system

Tags: usability, confirmation, deletion, admin

I'm working on User Management System in ASP.NET MVC3. Administrator/Editor can search, insert, update and delete other users from the system.

What should I do when admin/editor clicks on Delete user link? Should I redirect him to new yes/no confirmation page or display some jquery popup window?

Should I then redirect him to the home page and display message `The user has been successfully deleted from the system`, or simple redirection should be just fine?

Answer (score 10):

Why not the flash message:

`You've deleted the user Jon Doe. _Undo?_`

I'd personally rather give the user the ability to fail and fix it rather than impose popups and confirmations on every delete action.

Comment: +1 Worth a read is *[Never Use a Warning When you Mean Undo](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/neveruseawarning)*.

Answer (score 3):

I would  not opt for a separate confirmation pages or dialog boxes because I feel you * punish* a missclick too heavily.

Generally I don't like the flash message: what happens when they delete a user wrongfully  but for some reason miss the flash message (internet issues, just don't see it). I think you should only take this route if the action can be undone at a later stage (eg gmail).

**What I would go for:**

when the delete action is clicked, switch the delete action into a confirmation message

```
John Doo | edit | delete
```

when delete is clicked. remove the *edit | delete* actions with javascript into:

```
John Doo | delete user? yes no
```

"yes" deletes the user, "no" puts it back to the initial state

Answer (score 1):

You can surely ping the user for mistakenly clicking delete button. Show a popup or something. Then the redirection should happen to the users list page so that admin can verify that the user has been deleted along with a confirmation message *(user has been deleted)* at the top of the user list

Answer (score 1):

At my company we build last week (no joke ;) ) a user management page with ASP.NET MVC3 and we decided to have an delete icon (red cross) next to the user. If you click on this icon we display a popup message (realised with jQuery) where we ask whether he wants do delete User NAME. When he does, we display a success message above the user table.

The standard scaffolding way by ASP is this extra delete page but I think the user would feel this extra way to another page and back to much for this kind of task.

Answer (score 0):

Actions which cannot be undone or which are difficult to undo should always prompt for confirmation.

Similarly, most actions should give feedback saying they've been completed successfully or not.